# Fat Princess - Is the story different from the online game mode?

Tags: version-differences, fat-princess, psn

I want to know if the story in Fat Princess is different from the online mode or if it's the same thing with Bots? Is there something new in solo or this is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing new when playing offline.  The gameplay follows the same arena-style format.  It's exactly the same as the online matches, but the slots not filled with human players are filled with bots.  Purportedly, these bots are plagued with terrible A.I. issues.

---

[Source](http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/action/fatprincess/review.html?om_act=convert&om_clk=gssummary&tag=summary;read-review)